# Probability problem - broken chandelier and bulbs

Tags: probability

We have a chandelier with 5 spots to insert lightbulbs. 3 out of 5 are broken. We also have 5 lightbulbs. Same as the chandelier - 3 out 5 are broken. If we randomly screw all lightbulbs in all chandelier spots what is the probability that the chandelier will work? (The chandelier will "work" if at least 1 lightbulb is lit.)

@true blue anil - Thank you.

My solution so far was this:

we choose 5 bulbs out of 5 and then we do permutations.

The number of all events is 5!* 5C5 = 5!=120

The number of events for a non-working chandelier would be:

To make this easier, we can say that the first 3 chandelier spots are broken. So we choose 5 bulbs with 3 broken spots times 2 working bulbs with 2 broken spots. and then we do permutations

5C3 * 3! * 2C2 * 2! =120

which is wrong...

EDIT: I'm sorry for my bad questions, I have dyslexia which makes it REALLY hard to write questions please have patience with me

Comment: Pl. edit your post to include what you have already tried, and where you are facing difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

What's the probability that neither of the lightbulbs will be lit? For this to happen, both of the working lightbulbs need to be placed on a broken spot.